# Android - can see widget in my device but can't see it in any emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-widget

I made simple app widget and when I install it on my device I can see it on my device **but**
I can't see it on any emulator when I run it from eclipse... I tried Genymotion emulator and the emulator that come with adt bundle version... It just not appear in the widgets as in the device maybe someone know where it exists?

Answer (score 0):

Is this perhaps a difference in screen densities? Is your Genymotion emulator the same exact device as the one you are running on? If not, different screen densities could alter the layout (usually RelativeLayout) and cause some weird layout "errors" to occur.